# Getting unique values using dictionary - would like to understand more

Tags: vba, dictionary, ms-access

I have this code I made from studying multiple posts.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2RfI75Yfg8

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/storing-unique-values-from-advanced-filter-to-an-array.1048617/

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetTheUniqueValues()
    
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim rng_col_a As Range
    Dim col_a_last_row As Long
    Dim source_array As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim new_array As Variant
    
    dict.CompareMode = TextCompare
    
    col_a_last_row = ActiveSheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).row
    Set rng_col_a = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), ActiveSheet.Range("A" & col_a_last_row))

    source_array = rng_col_a
    
    For i = LBound(source_array) To UBound(source_array)
        If source_array(i, 1) <> "" Then dict(source_array(i, 1)) = Empty
    Next i
    
    new_array = dict.Keys
    
    For j = LBound(new_array) To UBound(new_array)
        ActiveSheet.Range("H" & j + 2).Value = new_array(j)
    Next j

End Sub
```

I would like to understand more about

```
If source_array(i, 1) <> "" Then dict(source_array(i, 1)) = Empty
```

I am new to VBA and programming in general so may I now what the "dict(source_array(i, 1)) = Empty" does and why this particular line of code is effective of only putting unique values in the dictionary.

What does it do if the condition is true?

What does it do if the condition is false?

Thank you.

Comment: That test has nothing to do with putting unique values into the dictionary: it only skips empty cells.  The dictionary itself manages the uniqueness of the keys.

Comment: so in a dictionary, keys should be unique, correct?

Comment: In a dictionary keys HAVE to be unique. It won't let you create keys that are the same.

Answer (score 1):

`If source_array(i, 1) <> "" Then dict(source_array(i, 1)) = Empty` only create a new key and do not allocate any value. If instead of `Empty` will be 1, the final result will be the same, due to the fact that only the dictionary (unique) **keys** count...

`dict.Keys` is an array (independent of the key item values) and only it is used by this code. A shorter version of dropping the dictionary keys would be (without iteration between the array elements):

```
ActiveSheet.Range("H2").Resize(UBound(new_array) + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(new_array)
```

A shorter (but interesting, I think) version, for the whole code, would be the next one (it does not need a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'):

```
Sub GetTheUniqueValues()
Dim source_array As Variant, sh As Worksheet, j As Long, col_a_last_row As Long
Set sh = ActiveSheet

col_a_last_row = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
source_array = sh.Range(sh.Range("A2"), sh.Range("A" & col_a_last_row)).Value
 With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For j = 1 To UBound(source_array)
        .Item(source_array(j, 1)) = Application.Index(source_array, j, 0)
    Next
    
    sh.Range("H2").Resize(.count, UBound(source_array, 2)) = Application.Index(.Items, 0, 0)
 End With
End Sub
```

It would be a bigger challenge to understand it. But still not something very complicated...

Answer (score 1):

Using `dict("a") = Empty` tells the `dict` dictionary that its element with key `a` has no value (is Empty).

If the `dict` dictionary doesn't have a key `"a"`, then the code `dict("a") = Empty` will create it.

That means when cycling through all the values in the source_array, it won't (can't) create duplicates. If key `"a"` already exists it'll just assign `Empty` to it again, if it doesn't exist, it'll create it.

This is better than trying to add keys e.g. using

```
dict.Add "a", Empty
```

Will only work if key "a" doesn't already exist, but e.g.

```
dict("a") = Empty
```

Will either assign Empty to key "a" or create it. It can't error like the first method.

---

The `If source_array(i, 1) <> ""` is simply checking that there is a value to create in the first place.

If it's `true` then it'll try to create the key, if it's false it'll just move to the next `i` value.